# Change type of complex (array and struct) columns spark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataframe with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ... (other columns)
 |-- my_array_col: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- col_a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col_b: date (nullable = true)
```

How can I change the type of col_b to a StringType?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast arbitrarily deep array and struct columns with the cast operator like so:

```
.withColumn("my_array_col", col("my_array_col")
    .cast("array<struct<col_a: string, col_b: string>>")
```